# find documents on the basis of array of object id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model with two roles

1. Manager
2. Employee

Each manager has an manager idea that references the User model

I have a new model called Customers
The customers will either have user id of manager or employee

I want to create a controller to view the customers that are under the manager and the employees of that manager

```
let employees= await Employee.find({ managerId: req.user._id });

const customers= await Customer.find({
      registeredBy: { $in: [employees._id] },
    });
```

this is only returning the customers that are NOT registered by any employee or manager. What is the correct way to achieve this?

**edit**
This is how my customer collection looks like

```
_id:ObjectId('61e2a99752f9023ef0f9a1a6')
serialNo:"421A"
registeredBy:ObjectId('61d02ae060ccdd5a7a95813a')
```

If the manager is searching, the record of all the Customers having that manager id as ***registeredBy*** as well as the Customers having ***registerBy*** of the employees that have that ***managerId in Employee schema** should be shown

Comment: Can you please add a collection examples and the expected output?

Comment: @J.F. i have edited the question